# Facebook graph excluding application posts

Tags: android, facebook, graph, feed

Developing an Android App integrated with Facebook.

After registering my app on Facebook, getting authorization etc - I`m able to post text and images to a users timeline. When I open the timeline in a browser - I see the posts displayed correctly. However, when I query the graph with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user id}/feed
```

the result includes everything of that users timeline, EXCEPT for the posts made by my application.

Any ideas why is this and how can I get the complete feed/the posts made by the application for this user only?

Comment: How were you making the original posts? With Open Graph actions?

Comment: Yes, I send the text/image using POST method to the user`s "me/feed" and "me/photos", eg: 
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "Hello Facebook");
parameters.putString("app_id", FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for not seeing the posts made by my App is that they when published, they will belong to the "USER/statuses" node, not "USER/feed" which I had expected. To me, this is rather confusing given that the only object publishing allowed by the Graph API is exactly "USER/feed" and that is the node which I call with my POST request.
Anyhow, upon querying with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user id}/statuses
```

the application posts are returned accordingly. I make the assumption that a user`s facebook wall combines statuses and posts.

I can not find a reference to any documentation from Facebook on this, if somebody knows of such - please share it.